# How to use list-style-type decimal but without the dots

Tags: css, list

Hi,

list-style-type decimal shows lists like this:

```
1. apple
2. pear
3. whatever
```

but I dont need the dot so it looks like this:

```
1 apple
2 pear
3 whatever
```

is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **[CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)** or **[CSS Markers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker)**. Ordered lists have a default counter named `list-item` you don't have to reset or increment, so the following is equivalent when using the default 0+1 ordering (starting at 0 and incrementing by 1)<sup>✻</sup>

<sup>There's a [bug in Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204163) that makes the CSS property `content` unuseable, as per [Sascha Klatt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2438049/sascha-klatt) comment.</sup>

<sup><sup>✻</sup> Thanks goes out to [fcrozatier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16126495/fcrozatier) for pointing out the default behavior of `list-item` of an `<ol>`.</sup>

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

/* ::before Solution */
.A {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

/* The "\a0" is a space */
.A li::before {
  content: counter(list-item)"\a0\a0";
}

/* ::marker Solution */
.B li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.B li::marker {
  content: counter(list-item)"\a0\a0";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Default style of &lt;ol&gt;</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>

<ol class='A'>
  <li>Custom style using <code>::before</code> pseudo-element</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>

<ol class='B'>
  <li>Custom style using <code>::marker</code> pseudo-element</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten those!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.

Comment: Seems like the `::marker` solution doesn't work on Safari.

Comment: there is an easier solution, can be done using @counter-style:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style